# Blink from loading (isPending) to resolved. Why?

Tags: javascript, performance, ember.js, ember-data

This is my ember-twiddle that explain the entire situation:

https://ember-twiddle.com/758a294c26d4f66b201462c997f79e57

My problem is the loading message.

My posts are sideloaded and it can be a very very long time for download.

In the meantime I need to show a loading message (in twiddle this is green).

When I enter the `category` route from `categories` route I need the green loading directly, not a blink with red as you can see.

Why it's happening?

Answer (score 0):

This type of data loading can get a bit tricky (as you've run into ;-).  In your setup, do you want your category to display if the data hasn't loaded?

If you don't, then you can block your UI loading by requesting that your posts data get side-loaded your category route model hook:

```
model(params) {
  return this.store.findRecord('category', params.category_id, { include: 'posts' });

  // see the guides page about this
  // https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/models/relationships/#toc_retrieving-related-records
}
```

Right now, your posts data request seems to be triggered by your template accessing the posts data (which is why you are seeing that flash).

If you do want to show category data while your post data loads (this is often the desired effect), then doing your secondary data loading in a posts component (that uses the appropriate category id) may be the cleanest way to handle this.

I've personally found using [ember-concurrency](http://ember-concurrency.com) for this type of task makes it much simpler.  This example might help point you in the right direction: http://ember-concurrency.com/#/docs/examples/autocomplete

Does that help?